# Textstream object remains open in Excel after being closed by VBA

Tags: vba, excel, csv

I have some VBA code in Excel 2007 which creates, fills, then closes a Textstream file object (abbreviated snippet below).

```
Set CSV = FSO.CreateTextFile(strPathOut & Application.PathSeparator & strFileOut)

'Fill the file

CSV.Close
```

The code works perfectly, including the `CSV.Close` instruction, however if I then try to delete or modify the file (e.g. in Windows Explorer or Notepad) the system claims Excel still has the file open.  Seemingly the only way to release it is to close Excel itself.

I've checked that `CSV.Close` is doing what it's supposed to from the VBA side; it's not causing a runtime error, and certainly the file is no longer available to be written to after that instruction.

My project is early bound to the Microsoft Scripting Runtime, scrrun.dll.  I've tried removing that reference but I get the same result.

This is not a showstopper for the project, but it's a PITA during development.  Anybody know what's going on?

Comment: what if  you additionally `Set CSV = Nothing` and the same for other object variables related to the project??

Comment: Thanks - this fixed it.  Apologies, I never got round to testing this before Robin Mackenzie posted it as an actual answer.

Comment: If `CSV` is declared in the same procedure, it should be getting destroyed when the procedure exits. Is your variable declared inside the procedure? You can also use the `FSO.OpenTextFile` method (and still force the creation of a new file if desired).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this simple example - the file is available for editing through e.g. Notepad, after the code has run:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test()

    Dim objFSO As New FileSystemObject
    Dim objStream As TextStream
    Dim i As Integer

    Set objStream = objFSO.CreateTextFile("D:\temp.txt")
    With objStream
        For i = 1 To 10
            .WriteLine CStr(i)
        Next i
        .Close
    End With

    Set objStream = Nothing
    Set objFSO = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Cheers.  Yep as originially mentioned by @KazimierzJawor it's the `Set obj = Nothing` that I was missing.